# Where can a Java program be invoked?

Tags: java

Suppose you add a "main" argument to the Java program you use. Then is the use for the Java program restricted to the Console in your IDE? In other words, can you only "use" that program   on the IDE?

Now suppose you DONT have a "main" argument in your Java program, like this: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100727161815AAZAd9p

It doesnt DO anything on the IDE (like when you press "run", it says you need a "main" argument). So then where can you even use that program?

Comment: You can run the `main` of a Java program from, eg, the Windows "DOS command line" by typing `java MyClassName` (without the `.class`).  With "JNI" interfaces you can invoke Java code (main or other interfaces) from C and other languages.

Answer (score 0):

This is broad question, requires long answer.

A class will be treated as main class if you tell JVM while executing `java` command (In IDE case, you can configure main class in "run configurations).

If you don't have `public static void main(String[] args) method` means that is not start of your execution. The class without main method will be instantiated (or) extended in another class (either main class/some other class) based on business functionality.

NOTE: Even though a class is with main method, it may not be "start" of execution based on application.

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering different classes other than the one listed in the example then you can consider abstract classes, interfaces that are used by other classes to achieve proper functionality. And when you consider applets, most applets don't have main methods, so there are a number of ways in which you can you a program without main. :)